# HAPI V2.6 context.close() throws NullPointerException

Tags: hapi

I am running a very simple test with the HAPI V2 library.

```
@Test
public void testHapiContext()
{
    HapiContext context = new DefaultHapiContext();
    try
    {
        context.close();
        assertTrue(true);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        fail("Close threw an exception");
    }
}
```

This JUnit test always fails because the close() method throws a NullPointer exception. Any idea why?

On the other hand I can do everything I want to do with the HAPI context except call close() but not calling close causes Eclipse to give me a leak warning.